# Neural net and category separation with interaction terms

Tags: neural-networks, interaction, accuracy, stochastic-gradient-descent

We have a stream of tabular data consiting of categorical and numerical features. One category is somehow crucial in either affecting the target, interacting with other features and sorting the data stream. Lets say the stream consists of 30K observations from category A on one day, 20K from category B the next day, and so on.

Now consider the simplified linear situation depicted in the following figure. The data is preprocessed in that way that it consists of interactions terms.

[image: Linear model for two categories]

At least without regularization, updating a Stochastic Gradient Descent Regression Model with a batch of observations from Category A does not change the coefficients for Group B which is the desired behaviour.

However, a linear model does not fit our needs in terms of accuracy but a simply multi-layer neural net does which is shown from experiments. But updating the net with data from Group A has an affect on the weights for category B and decreases the accuracy for category B.

What is the best strategy to deal with that problem? Why are the weights for category B changing when updating the net with data from category A? How can I prevent the neural net to degenerate the accuracy for category B when updating the weights with data from category A?